# Powershell - Left mouse click without moving mouse

Tags: powershell

I've done a bunch of searching and it seems that everybody that wants to use a mouse clicking event talks about moving the mouse.  I am using a different method that already has the object selected.  Literally the only thing I will need to do is a single left-click of the mouse.

I am not finding working code to do just this and only this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not.  Or, at least, it should not be.  As mentioned, every post I have found (including that one) discuss about moving the cursor around.  I do not want to do this.  And that is what the code in that post does.

Comment: @sbagnato it allows you to click a specific point on the screen, you can tell it to click the current mouse position by passing it the current mouse position? look up using windows forms and `[System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position`

Comment: The answer with the "older method"  `[W.U32]::mouse_event(6,0,0,0,0);` event 6 is just left mouse down, left mouse up without movement.

Comment: what about right click? I tried 5 and 7 not work